# ValueError on jsonify

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am very new to Flask and Python, I have to convert a MySql query to json format.
On converting, I am facing value error and unable to understand, please help me, thankyou in advance.

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 8; 2 is required on executing jsonify(r)`

```
@app.route('/post')
def display():
  cursor.execute("select * from tablename")
  result=cursor.fetchall()
  r = [dict((cursor.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in result]
 return jsonify(r)
```

Comment: What if you remove the list brackets and make it just a dict?

Comment: What version of flask are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's a better way to create dictionaries from MySQL queries, and it will get you around the error you're receiving.

When you define your cursor, you should have it return your query results as a list of dictionaries, like so:

`cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)`

That way each row of your table that is returned from the query will exist as a dictionary within a list. It would look something like this:

```
[
    {'firstcol': 'value1row1', 'secondcol': 'value2row1'... 'tenthcol': 'value10row1'},
    {'firstcol': 'value1row2', 'secondcol': 'value2row2'... 'tenthcol': 'value10row2'},
    ...
    {'firstcol': 'value1row50', 'secondcol': 'value2row50'... 'tenthcol': 'value10row50'}
]
```

Then, jsonifying your results becomes trivially easy:

`return jsonify(result)`

From there, you will have a JSON object with elements that can be referenced by key. If you want to display all values from 'firstcol', you need only `response['firstcol']` in your JavaScript file.

Also, just to make sure you're clear on Flask routing, titling your route '/post' does not define a 'POST' method for your route. You'd need:

`@app.route('/post' methods=['POST'])`

I apologize if you were already aware of this - I just started learning Flask a few months ago and was initially pretty confused about some of the conventions, so I imagine you may be in the same boat as I was.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of Flask. 0.12 changed `jsonify` to allow any type, previously only dicts and lists of tuples were allowed.

```
pip install -U flask
```